# SonarLint best practice for "hard coded password" false positives

Tags: java, sonarlint

SonarLint flags as blockers some variables in my code base. Ones like `public static final String INVALID_PASSWORD = "Your password is invalid.";`

SonarLint thinks that the variable might contain a hard coded password, which is a security risk. But in this case, the variable does not contain a password, it contains a message about a password.

I also have some like `public static final String INVALID_PASSWORD = "INVALID_PASSWORD";`, that are codes rather than strings, which SonarLint also flags.

What's the best practice for "fixing" this type of issue? Two solutions that come to mind are renaming the variable, and using a `@SupressWarnings("code here")` annotation.

Does SonarLint itself have a recommendation for this issue? Is an there an industry best practice?

Comment: The best practice is to choose the best possible name for your variables. If you think INVALID_PASSWORD is the best name, then ignore the warning. If you think there is a better name, then rename the variable.

Comment: The best practice depends on your needs, for example, the first string looks like something that is displayed to the end user - in such case it might be good to convert the string to resource. At least the C# version of the rule will not complain about resources, because they are considered autogenerated...

Answer (score 10):

You should be able to mute the Sonar issue with something like:

```
@SuppressWarnings("squid:S2068") // This is not an hard coded password.
```

Annotated over the culprit.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using SonarLint in connected mode with SonarQube,
then you can safely mark this issue as a *False Positive*.
That would be a recommended way to manage the quality of your software,
but it requires SonarQube.

If you are not using SonarQube, then currently there's no (good) way to suppress the issue in SonarLint.
It's quite possible that such feature will be implemented in SonarLint in the near future (this year).

Answer (score 0):

Renaming the variable name worked for me .

Example: previously it started with the text password like this: passwordCreationRules
Then I changed to rulesForPassword something like
Tip: Try avoiding using password text may be you can cut short it as pass or something like that which worked for me